# Proving convergence of $\sum (\sin n^2) (1-\cos \frac{1}{3n} )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried multiple approaches but I just can't find how to prove that this sum converges. Any hint will be much appreciated!
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin n^2) \left(1-\cos \frac{1}{3n} \right)$$

Wolfram says it's comparison test, I have no idea what they compared it to.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for cosine at zero? Can you think of an upper bound on $| \sin n^2 |$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $|\sin x| \le 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and that $1 - \cos x = 2 \sin^2 \frac x 2$. Knowing these and slipping the modulus inside the sum, we may write

$$\left| \sum _{n \ge 1} (\sin n^2) \left( 1 - \cos \frac 1 {3n} \right) \right| \le \sum _{n \ge 1} \underbrace{| \sin n^2 |} _{\le 1} \cdot \left| 2 \sin^2 \frac 1 {6n} \right| \le \sum _{n \ge 1} \left| 2 \sin^2 \frac 1 {6n} \right| = 2 \sum _{n \ge 1} \sin^2 \frac 1 {6n} .$$

For the last series, remember that $\lim _{x \to 0} \frac {\sin x} x = 1$, which means that the last series obtained has the same behaviour as

$$2 \sum _{n \ge 1} \left( \frac 1 {6n} \right)^2 = \frac 1 {18} \sum _{n \ge 1} \frac 1 {n^2}$$

which is known to be convergent, therefore the series given in the problem is convergent too.

Comment: Wait, but the limit comparison test requires $n->/infty$. You prove for $n->0$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion: I let $x = \frac 1 {3n}$, which means that $x \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, so there is nothing wrong there. Do not mistake $x$ for $n$!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter (but essentially the same) with *asymptotic analysis*:

As $;1-\cos\dfrac1{3n}=2\sin^2\dfrac1{6n}$ and $\;\sin\dfrac1{6n}\sim_\infty\dfrac1{6n}$, we have
$$\biggl\lvert\sin n^2\Bigl(1-\cos\dfrac1{3n}\Bigr)\biggr\rvert=O\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr),$$
which is convergent, hence the given series is absolutely convergent.